# Show $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{n_1}+\frac{(1-x)^2}{n_2}}-\min \left(\frac{n_1}{x}, \frac{n_2}{1-x}\right) \ge0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, real-numbers

I'm interested in the following function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{n_1}+\frac{(1-x)^2}{n_2}}-\min \left(\frac{n_1}{x}, \frac{n_2}{1-x}\right)$$

where $n_1, n_2$ can be any positive integer.

I have graphed the function with $n_1=50, n_2=70$, for example.

From my observations (and with other choices of $n_1, n_2$, the function $f$ is nonnegative on the real line. Moreover, the $\min$ argument is important because I encounter cases that the function without it is no longer positive.

But I'm not sure how to prove this function is nonnegative, especially given it has $\min$ argument in it.

P.S. My original question only cares the case $0\le x\le1$, i.e. $x$ and $1-x$ are the weights. But since I found the function $f$ is nonnegative over $\mathbb{R}$ on the plot I generated, I decided to phrase my question to $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

[image]

Comment: Looks fairly simple. Consider the cases $x >\frac {n_1}{n_1+n_2}$ and $x \le \frac {n_1}{n_1+n_2}$.

Comment: You probably want to exclude $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: I don't know why the question got down voted. It would be nice to have some suggestions for me to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Weighted Power Mean Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_mean_inequality) which states that the $p^{th}$ weighted power mean is an increasing function of $p$. In particular we will apply this to compare the $p=-1$ mean (which is the harmonic mean) with the $p=-\infty$ mean (which is the minimum), in symbols
$$
\frac{w_1+w_2}{w_1/x_1+w_2/x_2}=M_{-1}(x_1,x_2)\geq M_{-\infty}(x_1,x_2)=\min(x_1,x_2).
$$
Make the substitions
$$
w_1\mapsto x,\quad w_2\mapsto 1-x,\qquad x_1\mapsto n_1/x,\quad x_2\mapsto n_2/(1-x),
$$
to obtain that
$$
M_{-1}\left(\frac{n_1}{x},\frac{n_2}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x+(1-x)}{x/(n_1/x)+(1-x)/(n_2/(1-x))}=\frac{1}{x^2/n_1+(1-x)^2/n_2},
$$
and thus the inequality $M_{-1}\geq M_{-\infty}$ applied to this special case yields that
$$
\frac{1}{x^2/n_1+(1-x)^2/n_2}\geq \min\left(\frac{n_1}{x},\frac{n_2}{1-x}\right)
$$
as desired.

Comment: This works only if both $x$ and $1-x$ are positive.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry that is my bad. The original question is indeed about weights - but I don't know how to ask that question properly. Therefore I translate it into the current question. I will edit my question.

Comment: In fact, the original inequality as stated by @maskeran makes sense for all $x\in\mathbb R$ if one interprets the right side as a suitable limit when $x\to 0$ or $x\to 1$ (since only one of the two terms in the minimum blows up to infinity simultaneously, the other stays finite). Moreover, my argument extends to all $x\in \mathbb R$ by first considering the case $0<x<1$, then taking the limit to extend to $0\leq x\leq 1$, and finally when $x<0$ or when $x>1$ the right side goes negative while the left side remains non-negative - essentially the only interesting case is when $0<x<1$.